# Index on one column, two columns, or both?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a simple table `user_id`(INT), `date`(DATE), and `earnings`(FLOAT). I am trying to decide how to index this table.

Currently, I have PRIMARY key set to `user_id`,`date`.

But not all queries are using this key. I have pasted some example queries below. All of these are ran frequently.

```
SELECT SUM(earnings) FROM stats WHERE user_id=? //Get total earnings
SELECT SUM(earnings) FROM stats WHERE user_id=? AND date between ? AND ? //Get earnings for date range

SELECT user_id FROM stats WHERE date=$today ORDER BY earnings DESC LIMIT 0,5 //Get todays highest earners
SELECT user_id FROM stats WHERE date>$month ORDER BY earnings DESC LIMIT 0,5 //Get months highest earners
```

As you can see, the top two queries use the index nicely, but the second two do not.

I was thinking of creating an index on `date`,`earnings` but feel weird about it since `date` is already in an index. Is this the correct solution?

If not, what is the best way to index this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking of creating an index on date,earnings but feel weird about it since date is already in an index.

It is OK to include the same column in multiple indexes as needed. Creating an index on `date,earnings` is definitely OK, but a single index on `date` would probably be sufficient as well. You could also consider indexing `date` and `user_id` separately, and see if the second query executes in roughly the same time (it should).

Comment: user_id and date have to stay in at least one unique index together. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the size of data that is the result of the date predicate.  If it's large (thousands of records), then the `ORDER BY` could benefit greatly from an index on earnings.  If it's relatively small, then you might not be see much benefit from the index, in fact, you might be doing yourself a disservice for inserts, updates, and deletes, if that happens often on this table.

In your example, where you have a predicate on only `date`, the composite primary key of `(user_id, date)` would not benefit you because composite key indexes work left-to-right, meaning there's an index look-up on `user_id` and `user_id, date`, but not `date` alone.

Off topic, but `float` is not a good data type for currencies.

Comment: Yes, I do realize the key doesnt apply to all the queries, which is why I was asking. Thanks for the answer! What is is a better data type for earnings?